# Node js promises with nested loops

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I was banging my head around this now for while but I can't solve this.
From Module_A I call a method in Module_B with promises. In this method I use nested each loops an I have a problem by using the right syntax.

I try to break this down. In this example the array locations[] is always empty and I can't resolve it to Module_A back.

Module_A:

```
app.listen(server_connection.port, () => {
console.log('Server started on port ' + server_connection.port);
getRegions() // This works
  .then(function(response){
    return constructionsiteParser.constructionsiteParser(response); // here is the problem to receive the array from Module_B 
  })
  .then(function(locations){
    console.log(locations.length);
  })
  .catch(function(msg){
    console.error(msg);
  });
});
```

Module_B:

```
var locations = [];

exports.constructionsiteParser = function constructionsiteParser(xmlArr){
var promise = new Promise (function(resolve, reject){
  getLocations(xmlArr)
    .then(function(locations){
      console.log(locations); //locations is empty and can't resolve it to Module_A
      if(objArr > 0){
        resolve(locations);
      }else{
        reject("Locations array is empty");
      }
    })
 });
 return promise;
}


let getLocations = function(xmlArr){
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      var $ = cheerio.load(xmlArr[0]);
      $('situation').each( function(){
          parseImportantInfos($, this)
            .then(function(obj){
              locations.push(obj);
            })
      });
    resolve(locations); // the problem must be somewhere here. This resolve will be executed bevor the eachloop from above is done
})
}


let parseImportantInfos = function($, record){
 return new Promise (function(resolve, reject){
   $(record).find('situationRecord').each( function(i){
      //do some stuff
      if(startLocationCode != '' && endLocationCode != '' ){
        Promise.all([
          //do some stuff
        ])
        .then( values =>{
          // do some stuff
        })
        .then(function(obj){
          resolve(obj);
        })
        .catch((err) =>{
           reject("There was an error while parsing the xml");
           console.log('err', err.stack);
       });
      }
   });
   });
  };
```

What I want is to return the complete locations array back to Module_A

Comment: You type `resolve(objArr)`, so you're resolving the objArary but inside getLocations you never add any values to objArr. So of course the promise is resolving empty. So when you do `getLocations(xmlArr)
    .then(function(locations){`, locations is the empty array you just resolved.

Comment: this was a copy paste mistake, I corrected it

Comment: Well I know why your result is empty. parseImportantInfos is asynchronous, but you resolve locations outside of the '.then', so... parseImportantInfos doesn't actually get a chance to run before you resolve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of

```
let getLocations = function(xmlArr){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
          var $ = cheerio.load(xmlArr);
          $('situation').each( function(){
              parseImportantInfos($, this)
                .then(function(obj){
                  locations.push(obj);
                })
          });
        resolve(locations); // the problem must be somewhere here. This resolve will be executed bevor the eachloop from above is done
    })
}
```

you'd want to use something like

```
let getLocations = function(xmlArr){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var $ = cheerio.load(xmlArr);
        var promiseList = [];
        $('situation').each( function(){
            var newPromise = parseImportantInfos($, this)
            .then(function(obj){
                locations.push(obj);
            })
            promiseList.push(newPromise)
        });

        Promise.all(promiseList).then(function(){
            resolve(locations);
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. but there must be more errors in the code. cause it is not working. I wound another one. xmlArr have to be xmlArr[0] but its still not working.

Comment: It works till `promiseList.push(newPromise)` and stops at `Promise.all(promiseList)....`

Comment: well set a breakpoint there, at Promise.all(promiseList), and inspect the promiseList, make sure it's an array full of promises.

Comment: in console.log(newPromise) is `Promise { <pending> }` but in the node-inspector it's `undefined`

Comment: right bevore `Promise.all` the `console.log(promiseList)` prints the hole list with Promise { <pending> }. But right after that it stocks at `Promise.all..`

Comment: At this point it seems like you just need to figure out how to debug it. If this is running in Node, you can use something like Webstorm to have breakpoints set. If it's in browser, you can use Chrome's dev tools. Worst case scenario, make wise use of console.log.

Comment: Use the free [visual studio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-tutorial) to set breakpoints and debug node.js code

Comment: So according to the visual studio code the debugger try to run the Promise.all first and after that it runs the eachloop in this sequence. But at the Promise.all the promiseList is already full of promises. Please see this screenshot: https://imgur.com/bIeGNKL

Comment: Yes, that's how it should happen. I'm going to refer to line numbers in your screenshot to describe how the program flow should run. If you set breakpoints on lines 31, 33, 39 and 41, because of how asynchronous functions work, it should stop at line 31 a bunch of times, then at line 39, then at line 33 a bunch of times, and then at line 41. You should read up on how javascript asynchronous stuff, and promises, work.

Comment: ok yes you are right, except of the last part, it never reaches line 41

Comment: ok so does it reach line 45? and if so, what's the error message?

Comment: finally I solved it. It was because the resolve in the `parseImportantInfos` method was inside a if() so sometimes there was no resolve. Thanks, you helped me a lot. I will accept your answer